# Second jQuery.post request finishing before first one. How to avoid this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .post

I'm trying to implement a search bar like facebook for my website users. While you type the name, some results are displayed. 
To avoid sending a request for each button pressed, i've setup a timeout. The idea is: if i'm going to type `jack` It doesn't make sense to search for `j`, `ja`, `jac`, `jack`, but it's better to wait for the users finishes typing before sending any request. 
Once the request is sent and completes, a div called `mydiv` is filed with results (the request response). If after some time long enough i type another letter, another request is sent and `mydiv` is filled with new results.

The idea comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318575/jquery-search-as-you-type-with-ajax).
Here is my simplified implementation.

```
var thread = null;    

$('#search-user').keyup(function() {
  clearTimeout(thread);
  name = $('this').val(); //i get the name just typed
  thread = setTimeout(function(){ 
    get_data_with_ajax_and_put_it_in_mydiv(name);
  }, 200);              
});

function get_data_with_ajax_and_put_it_in_mydiv(name){
  $.post()....
  /*Do some stuff*/
}
```

As you can see, after a 200ms timeout the function `get_data_with_ajax_and_put_it_in_mydiv();` is called. This function, emptys `mydiv` before putting new data. It works almost always, but sometimes a strange bug occurs.

I'm going to explain where i think the problem is, by providing a real example. Let us assume that `get_data_with_ajax_and_put_it_in_mydiv()` takes from 50ms to 1000ms to complete, depending on various factors (network speed, congestion, etc...).

- At `t=0` i type `jac` and i stop typing.
- At `t=200` the timeout expires and `get_data_with_ajax_and_put_it_in_mydiv()` runs. In this case it takes 1000ms to run
- At `t=210`, because i'm a slow writer, i type the letter `k` of `jack`. `mydiv` is empty because
  the first request has not yet completed.
- At `t=410` the timeout for the letter `k` epires and a second request
  is sent. This time, the function takes 100ms to run.
- At `t=510` the second request finishes and i get the results for `jack`.
- At `t=1200` the first request finishes and i get the results for `jac`.

**ERROR**

As you can see due to impredictability of time elaped by ajax requests i got a wrong result. `mydiv` is filled with `jac` results and not `jack`.

**SOLUTION**

The first solution that came to my mind is the following: every time i call `get_data_with_ajax_and_put_it_in_mydiv()` i have to stop any previous request still running. How can i do that? If not possible, how can i fix this error?

Comment: Aborting previous requests sounds like a good idea. Here is how to abort an Ajax request: http://stackoverflow.com/a/446626/678801

Comment: Quick and dirty solution would be to include the search string in your returned results and compare it to the last search string you sent. If it's not the same, just ignore the results.

Comment: Try sending a timestamp to the request and return the same timestamp. You store this timestamp in a global var and update it each request. When a request is complete, before you update the div content, check if the timestamp is the same of the request. You'll have always the last request result on the div.

Comment: You can also abort the request as @ChristoferEliasson suggested, but there's still a chance that you might abort it just a fraction too late.

Comment: I did as Christofer Eliasson suggested and it seems working...tried 50 times and no error, while previously i got error like 4-5 times. @MattBurland what do u mean?

Comment: It's probably rare, but it's possible that you might try to abort a request right after it completed anyway. Running it 50 times, it'll probably not happen, but put it in production and have it running millions of times and it might well pop up sporadically. Because of that, I'd either return the original request with your data or timestamp as @DontVoteMeDown suggested just for a sanity check. I wouldn't rely only on the timing of an abort always taking care of it. Also remember that an abort won't stop the server from processing the request. if it's already got it.

Comment: @MattBurland you're right. Personally, I preffer receive and ignore *no-more-important-requests* than manage them and cancel etc because of performance. As you said, it will not prevent server to proccess and it will be frequent cancel and already received request.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a debounced function to handle the ajax call?

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Promise interface and use the 'done' method to chain these two operations sequentially

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: This is an option, but in this particular case it seems unnecessary. If a response for `jack` has already been received, nobody cares about the result from the request for `jac` so why waste time waiting for it to finish? In other scenarios where the later request doesn't completely supersede the earlier one, this would be the way to handle it.